# Struct type aliasing / tagged-union without union

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

For two (or more) `struct`s: `Base` and `Sub` with a common first (unnamed) `struct`, is it safe to convert/cast from `Base` to `Sub` and vice versa?

```
struct Base{
    struct{
        int id;
        // ...
    };
    char data[]; // necessary?
}

struct Sub{
    struct{
        int id;
        // same '...'
    };
    // actual data
};
```

Are these functions guaranteed to be safe and technically correct? (Also: is the zero-length `char data[]` member necessary and useful?)

```
struct Base * subToBase(struct Sub * s){
    return (struct Base*)s;
}

struct Sub * baseToSub(struct Base * b){
    if(b->id != SUB_ID){
        return NULL;
    }

    return (struct Sub*)b;
}
```

**Edit**

I have no plans to nest any further than `Base` within `Sub`, but rather leave the possibility to add other sub-types (directly under `Base`) later without needing to change `Base`. My main concern is whether pointers to the `struct`s can be safely converted back and forth between `Base` and any sub. References to the (C11) standard would be most appreciated.

**Edit v2**

Changed the wording slightly to discourage OOP/inheritance discussions. What I want is a tagged-union, without the `union` so it can be extended later. I have no plans for doing additional nesting. Sub-types that need other sub-types' functionality can do so explicitly, without doing any further nesting.

---

#### Context

For a script interpreter<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule)</sup> I have made a <s>pseudo object-oriented</s> [tagged-union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) type system, without the `union`. It has <s>an (abstract)</s> *generic* base type `Object` with several *(specific)* sub-types, such as `String`, `Number`, `List` etc. Every type-`struct` has the following unnamed `struct` as the first member:

```
#define OBJHEAD struct{    \
    int id;                \
    int line;              \
    int column;            \
}
```

The `id` identifies the type of object, `line` and `column` should (also) be self-explanatory. A simplified implementation of various objects:

```
typedef struct Object{
    OBJHEAD;

    char data[]; // necessary?
} Object;

typedef struct Number{
    OBJHEAD;

    int value; // only int for simplicity
} Number;

typedef struct String{
    OBJHEAD;

    size_t length;
    char * string;
} String;

typedef struct List{
    OBJHEAD;

    size_t size;
    Object * elements; // may be any kind and mix of objects
} List;

Object * Number_toObject(Number * num){
    return (Object*)num;
}

Number * Number_fromObject(Object * obj){
    if(obj->type != TYPE_NUMBER){
        return NULL;
    }

    return (Number*)obj;
}
```

I know that the most elegant and technically correct way to do this would be to use an `enum` for the `id` and a `union` for the various sub-types. But I want the type-system to be extensible (through some form of type-registry) so that types can be added later without changing all the `Object`-related code.

A later/external addition could be:

```
typedef struct File{
    OBJHEAD;

    FILE * fp;
} File;
```

without needing to change `Object`.

Are these conversions guaranteed to be safe?

(As for the small macro-abuse: the `OBJHEAD` will of course be extensively documented so additional implementers will know what member-names not to use. The idea is not to hide the header, but to save pasting it every time.)

Comment: If you can/want to use gcc extensions, you might find `-fplan9-extensions` **very** interesting.

Comment: @Olaf My plan is to be as technically correct and strictly conforming as possible. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: As far as the base members share the same size in memory, yes, it is possible. It's the same as the `struct sockaddr` family which you could a take a look at. Are you looking for the normative wording?

Comment: You still can use C99 anonymous struct members (without the extensions you need to `#define`, though). The extensions actually provide (almost) true OOP but without the overhead and much more type-safety. I think this is much more important than sticking to the standard - as long as it is a widely used OSS tollchain. I would refran from using such on a commercial or seldom used tool, however.

Comment: @Olaf if I understand correctly anonymous struct members were newly standardized with C11. My current implementation compiles with GCC4.8.2 with `-Wall -pedantic -std=c11` without error or warning. @black: yes, references to the standard would be preferred. I'll add the [tag:c11] tag.

Comment: If I read it correctly, I wrote C99, not C11. C11 did add no extras here. For such a project, I'd either use the extension (reasons given above), or switch to C++ (not my favourite choice).

Comment: See [this post on the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). In particular, BenVoigt's answer contains the relevant section from the C standard. However, that section of the standard is probably the most poorly written section of a very poorly written document. Which is why this question has been asked numerous times without ever receiving a satisfactory answer. Instead you'll get answers in both the affirmative and the negative, with a stream of debating comments appended to each.

Comment: @user3386109 I was hoping my case would be clearer due to the common first-member, but after reading that section a few more times I'm still not much wiser. Could this question be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @user3386109, your comment came in while I was typing my answer. Perhaps it clarifies that point?

Comment: @Kninnug I would actually like to see this question get a definitive answer, so I'm not inclined to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @JensGustedt Although I tend to agree with your position, the counter-example is the `struct sockaddr` and `struct sockaddr_in` used by Berkeley sockets.

Comment: In general, my position is that the C spec should specifically allow overlaying different structure types that share the same initial members. And I'm inclined to believe that the spec actually does allow this (in a horribly round-about obfuscated way) so as to grandfather in the Berkeley socket interface.

Comment: @user3386109, that network interface is horrific and broken. You only can program it reliably in situations where aliasing may occur by using `union`s, or by getting the guaranties from outside that two objects that are typed differently will never be the same. Otherwise, for your "in general" in don't think so. Types being different (plus eventually using `restrict`) is the only possibility for a C compiler to deduce something about aliasing. This is built into all compilers and brings noticeable performance improvements.

Comment: @JensGustedt I agree that Berkeley sockets are horrific, but what is the alternative for a C programmer? A quick search for [Posix sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#See_also) indicates that Posix sockets are the same as Berkeley sockets.

Comment: @user3386109 sure there is no alternative. You just have to program really carefully.

Comment: @user3386109: Any sane spec for a C dialect would allow it, and I would posit that sane compilers should behave as though the spec compelled them to allow it, whether it does or not, but modern compilers will sometimes, unpredictably, yield arbitrary behavior if code writes a member of the common initial sequence using one type and reads it using another.

Answer (score 4):

Converting a pointer to one object type to a pointer to a different object type (via a cast, for instance) is permitted, but if the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned then behavior is undefined (C11 6.3.2.3/7).  Depending on the members of `Base` and `Sub` and on implentation-dependent behavior, it is not necessarily the case that a `Base *` converted to a `Sub *` is correctly aligned.  For example, given ...

```
struct Base{
    struct{
        int id;
    };
    char data[]; // necessary?
}

struct Sub{
    struct{
        int id;
    };
    long long int value;
};
```

... it may be that the implementation permits `Base` objects to be aligned on 32-bit boundaries but requires `Sub` objects to be aligned on 64-bit boundaries, or even on stricter ones.

None of this is affected by whether `Base` has a flexible array member.

It is a different question whether it is safe to dereference a pointer value of one type that was obtained by casting a pointer value of a different type.  For one thing, C places rather few restrictions on how implementations choose to lay out structures: members must be laid out in the order they are declared, and there must not be any padding before the first one, but otherwise, implementations have free reign.  To the best of my knowledge, in your case there is no requirement that the anonymous `struct` members of your two structures must be laid out the same way as each other if they have more than one member.  (And if they have only one member then why use an anonumous struct?)  It is also not safe to assume that `Base.data` starts at the same offset as the first element following the anonymous struct in `Sub`.

In practice, dereferencing the result of your `subToBase()` is probably ok, and you can certainly implement tests to verify that.  Also, if you have a `Base *` that was obtained by conversion from a `Sub *`, then the result of converting it back, for instance via `baseToSub()`, is guaranteed to be the same as the original `Sub *` (C11 6.3.2.3/7 again).  In that case, the conversion to `Base *` and back has no effect on the safety of dereferencing the the pointer as a `Sub *`.

On the other hand, though I'm having trouble finding a reference for it in the standard, I have to say that `baseToSub()` is very dangerous in the general context.  If a `Base *` that does not actually point to a `Sub` is converted to `Sub *` (which in itself is permitted), then it is *not* safe to dereference that pointer to access members not shared with `Base`.  In particular, given my declarations above, if the referenced object is in fact a `Base`, then `Base.data` being declared in no way prevents `((Sub *)really_a_Base_ptr)->value` from producing undefined behavior.

To avoid all undefined and implementation-defined behavior, you want an approach that avoids casting and ensures consistent layout.  @LoPiTaL's suggestion to embed a typed `Base` structure inside your `Sub` structures is a good approach in that regard.

Comment: So, as long as I honour the implicit contract that all conversions from `Base` to `Sub` only happen on objects that were created as a `Sub`, the only remaining problem is possible alignment issues. Could I use the [`alignas` (/ `_Alignas`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) operator to mitigate those?

Comment: If you are certain to cast from `Base *` to `Sub *` only for objects that were created as `Sub`, then there is no alignment problem associated with that.  You do not need `alignas` for that.  With your proposed approach there is still the issue that the first part of `Sub` might not be laid out the same way as `Base`, however.  I think you're *unlikely* to run into that in practice, but if you're looking for guarantees then C does not provide one in that area.

Comment: @Kninnug, also, Jens's comments about pointer aliasing and optimization are still relevent no matter under what circumstances you cast pointers to different types, whereas I don't think they apply if you avoid casting, including by embedding a `Base` in a `Sub`.  You can probably tell your compiler to disable such optimizations, but you would have to do so for every compiler you forecast using.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not safe, at least not under all circumstances. If your compiler sees two pointers `p` and `q` that have different base type, it may always assume that they don't alias, or stated in other words it may always assume that `*p` and `*q` are different objects.

Your cast punches a hole in that assumption. That is if you have a function

```
double foo(struct A* p, struct B* q) {
   double b = q->field0;
   *p = (struct A*){ 0 };
   return b + q->field0;       // compiler may return 2*b
}
```

the optimizer is allowed to avoid the additional read from memory.

If you'd *know* that no function will ever see the same object through differently typed pointers, you would be safe. But such an assertion is not made easily, so you'd better avoid such hackery.

Comment: Also state that to avoid this "optimization", you can add the "volatile" keyword to the pointers definitions, forcing the compiler to perform the actual read.

Comment: @LoPiTaL, no unfortunately just using `volatile` for the pointer types doesn't always help. The compiler is only force to take this into account if the object itself had been declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, since it is guaranteed to have the same alignment on the first member of the struct, so you can cast from one struct to another.

Nevertheless, the common way to implement your behaviour is to "inherit" the base class:

```
//Base struct definition
typedef struct Base_{
    int id;
    // ...
    //char data[]; //This is not needed.
}Base;

//Subclass definition
typedef struct Sub_{
    Base base;  //Note: this is NOT a pointer
    // actual data
}Sub;
```

So now, you can cast a Sub struct into a Base struct, or just return the first member, which already is of type Base, so there is no need of casting anymore.

One word of caution: do not abuse MACROS. MACROS are nice and good for a lot of things, but abusing them may lead to difficult to read and maintain code.
In this case, the macro is easily replaced with the base member.

One final word, your macro is error prone, since the member names are now hidden. On the end, you may be adding new members with the same name, and getting weird errors without knowing why.

When you further expand your hierarchy into sub-subclasses, you will end up having to write ALL the base classes MACRO, while if you use the "inherit" aproach, you will have to write only the direct base.

Neither of these solutions actually solve your problem: inheritance. The only real solution you would have (the preferred) would be to change to a trully OO language. Due to similarity to C, the best match would be C++, but could do any other language.

Comment: I hadn't considered using the bare `struct` to include `Base` in `Sub`, but it does mean I can no longer access the `Base`-members directly through sub (`struct Sub * s; s->id ...` would become `s->base.id`). Not disastrous, but would require some refactoring. Also the `OBJHEAD` macro is `#undef`ed at the end of the type definitions, but I understand your concerns there.

Comment: Macros are not evil if you are aware of their pitfalls. In C, they are the way to define **true** symbolic constants and implement template-like features.

Comment: NMDV, yet in C, macros have their proper uses - especially typed or compile-time computed constants.  Of course users abuse them too.  "RUN AWAY FROM MACROS ALWAYS YOU CAN!!" takes aways from an otherwise good answer.

Comment: @Kninnug The `#undef`inition is not the problem. Problem is that your code is error prone. You stated that you want code safe and technically correct. Technically correct is almost all code. But yours is not code safe

Comment: @Kninnug: This will become a nightmare of maintenance (believe me, I tried!). Without extensions, you are better off using the macro than nesting (and nesting (and nesting)) base-classes.

Comment: @Olaf I know macros are necessary in C. Abusing them is evil. In this case, he is abusing them. I have updated the answer to state it

Comment: @Olaf Entire libraries are written with this pattern. I.e. the entire ffmpeg is written this way... Is the way to go... or move to C++

Comment: "Technically correct is almost all code." I wonder where the UB comes from then. And no, I disagree. It is cumbersome and if he is limited to strict conforming code, I'd not use C here, but it is the lesser evil than nesting base-classes that deep.

Comment: @LoPiTaL: Sounds like "Eat feces! millions of flies can't be wrong!" to me. As I already wrote, I'd go with Plan9-extensions if allowed, otherwise C++ (at least here I agree). Only if both are not possible, I'd use the macro approach - possibly (we do not know all contraints).

Comment: Well, if he is not Ok with nesting base-classes, then C is not his language. Then he has to move to a trully OO language.

Comment: I have no plans to do any further nesting than `Base` in `Sub`, but rather leave the possibility open for other `Sub`s (for wrapping `FILE*`-handles or sockets into `Object`s). My main concern is whether the pointers to the `struct`s can safely be cast back and forth. I'll update the question to elaborate.

Comment: I removed my DV. You added some good points. For generating derived classes, I hope the next release of the standard will finally make anonymous struct members fully usable as the Plan9-Extensions already do.

Comment: Just one last comment, if he is nesting so deep, he will end up with many many base classes MACROS.... it will be a nightmare to maintain. //// The comment was written before reading your last comment

Comment: @Kninnug: "I have no plans to do any further nesting ..." I wish I'd got one cent every time I said that and I plans changed - sometimes after few hours.

Comment: @LoPiTaL: That's why I try to talk him into (at least) considering using the extensions or change to C++ (I for myself don't like it, but YMMV).

Comment: @Olaf I'll give you that. Fortunately this is only a hobby project, intended to explore how masochisticly standardly I can write still-usable code. Rewriting everything from scratch is not unprecedented (a previous version did use an `enum` and `union` in `Base`).

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to reflect that another (preferred) aproach would be to change to an OO language

Comment: That would be the standard way, yes. IMO the main target is to avoid unnecessary casts; whcih you do need a lot your way.

Comment: @Kninnug: "this is only a hobby project" Even better, as you can explore true OOP features in a known language and without additional syntax :-)

Comment: Ah, but my problem is not actually inheritance. Maybe the question is a bit misleading on that, I'll try to rewrite again. The `Base` class isn't so much a class, but rather a `void *` pointer with some extra (common) data and a type-tag. If a sub-type would need to use the functionality of another sub-type they can just do that explicitly rather than incur further nesting.