# Remove code redundancy in C through argument type abstraction

Tags: c, polymorphism, void-pointers, variable-types

I'm looking for a way to remove code redundancy.

I have two structures `A` and `B` having member variables `x` and `y`. A third structure `C` contains two linked lists, one with `A*` items, the other with `B*` items. The linked list implementation is not important except for the fact that its nodes store `void*` data. Therefore accessing the items of this linked list requires knowing if the `void*` data should be cast to `A*` or `B*`.

Here are the structs I'm using:

```
typedef struct {
    int x; 
    int y;
    double z;
} A;

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char t;
} B;

typedef struct {
    LinkedList* some_as;
    LinkedList* some_bs;
} C;
```

Now, the problem is that I have two very similar functions determining the indexes in the two linked lists in `C` where new `A*` and `B*` items should be inserted, based on the values of `x` and `y`. Here is how these functions look like:

```
int func_for_a(C* c, A* a) 
{
    int index = -1;
    for (Node* node = c->some_as->head; node; node = node->next) {
        ++index;
        A* current = (A*) node->data;
        // some checks on a->x, current->x, a->y, and current->y
        // these checks affect `index'
    }
    return index;
}

int func_for_b(C* c, B* b) 
{
    int index = -1;
    for (Node* node = c->some_bs->head; node; node = node->next) {
        ++index;
        B* current = (B*) node->data;
        // same checks on b->x, current->x, b->y, and current->y
        // these checks affect `index'
    }
    return index;
}
```

What I would like to do is to abstract the type of item (either `A*` or `B*`) that needs to be inserted in one of the two linked lists in `C`, along the lines of:

```
int func_for_a_or_b(C* c, TYPE type, void* item)
{
    Node* head;
    if (TYPE == A) {
        item = (A*) item; 
        head = C->some_as->head;
    } else {
        item = (B*) item;
        head = C->some_bs->head;
    }

    int index = -1;
    for (Node* node = head; node; node = node->next) {
        ++index;
        (TYPE)* current = (TYPE*) node->data;
        // checks on current->x, item->x, current->y, and item->y
        // these checks affect `index'
    }
    return index;
}
```

This is not possible because I cannot access members `x` and `y` of a `void* item`. How do I abstract the type of item? Could a macro be used? Is there another solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638875/3742943 The question is a bit different, but the answer is completely applicable to your case. The main concept is just create a base struct, and all of your inherited structs must have an instance of it (not a pointer) in their first field.

Comment: Thanks @LoPiTaL, but if I `typedef struct { int x; int y; } Coord` and exchange the `void* item` argument of `func_for_a_or_b` with a `Coord coord` variable, I am obliged to use a **non**-anonymous struct in `A` and `B` (and I'd really like to avoid doing the whole `a->coord.x` thing).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the whole discussion in the comments of the answer. You only have that option or another involving MACROS, also commented in that question, in another answer.

Comment: This is where C++ object hierarchies add power. Much C code is full of these casts from void pointers or from nested objects, and it is all rather hard to maintain.

Comment: An example of mixing both, the inheritance (in order to mantain the alignment) and the macros (in order to reduce code repetition) could be using anonymous unions: https://ideone.com/8aiV3G But I am with @GemTaylor, maybe it is time to move to C++...

Comment: @LoPiTaL, thanks for the clarification and the code example.

Comment: @GemTaylor, it's just for my C pet project: a 4X turn-based strategy game that is 100% C, just to see if I can get to write something clean, intelligible and easily maintainable. But I see your point.